# My OpenSSL certificates fail with Mosquitto

Tags: openssl, mqtt

I am trying to automate the creation of certificates, using the steps from a StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70337211/2803488).
These are the commands I'm trying:

1. `openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048`
2. `openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca-cert-request.csr -sha256`
3. `openssl x509 -req -in ca-cert-request.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca-root-cert.crt -days 365 -sha256`
4. `openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048`
5. `openssl req -new -key server.key -out server-cert-request.csr -sha256`
6. `openssl x509 -req -in server-cert-request.csr -CA ca-root-cert.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360`

In step 2, I am leaving the Common Name blank.  In step 5 I have tried `localhost` and the actual hostname for the Common Name.

When I run `mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t mqttsTest42 -p 8883 -m testMessage --cafile "C:\Certificates\ca-root-cert.crt" --cert "C:\Certificates\server.crt" --key "C:\Certificates\server.key"` it outputs this:

```
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.
```

If I run Mosquitto manually, it gives this:

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto>mosquitto -c mosquitto.conf -v
1669685112: mosquitto version 2.0.14 starting
1669685112: Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
1669685112: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1669685112: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1669685112: mosquitto version 2.0.14 running
1669685121: New connection from ::1:49375 on port 8883.
1669685121: Sending CONNACK to auto-7484C261-71E1-F653-3807-74471901380A (0, 5)
1669685121: Client auto-7484C261-71E1-F653-3807-74471901380A disconnected, not authorised.
```

I had this working with Mosquitto and another broker at one point.  In my effort to automate this, I have changed too many things, and now cannot even get the original six steps above to work for me anymore.

I am currently using mosquitto version `2.0.14` and OpenSSL version `3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022)`.  I have tried one other version of Mosquitto, and one other version of OpenSSL.

The batch file I created is [here](https://gist.github.com/AdamJHowell/a54f606a8111c4ea88d593ac2d06ab9c).
My openssl.cnf is [here](https://gist.github.com/AdamJHowell/3a385e6fd732d35a4d61e8e994bab935).

My mosquitto.conf contains these lines:

```
listener 8883
certfile C:\Certificates\server.crt
keyfile C:\Certificates\server.key
cafile C:\Certificates\ca-root-cert.crt
```

What should I try next?

Comment: Some of the links used in my automation research: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106525/generate-csr-and-private-key-with-password-with-openssl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294689/how-to-generate-an-openssl-key-using-a-passphrase-from-the-command-line
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692537/openssl-csr-creation-with-subj-is-failing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842768/passing-csr-distinguished-name-fields-as-parameters-to-openssl

Comment: I tried to replicate  your steps and `mosquitto.conf` file but its throwing a different error for me -- TLS/SSL error. I don't have time to dedicate to it right now but I'll look at it some more over the next few days and see if I can come up with anything if you don't have a better answer by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this has nothing to do with the OpenSSL/Certificate side of things. If this were a problem the error message would say something about TLS error or handshake failed or something like that -- I don't remember what the error message I got when it happened to me said.

The error messages you're getting however suggest TLS happened fine and the CONNACK is coming from mosquitto at the application level.

I would check your `mosquitto.conf` file; I suspect there is some permission settings or ACL in there that's restricting publish access to the mqttsTest42 topic which is why it kicks the client off for trying to publish to it.

Comment: The `mosquitto.conf` setting that I had wrong was `allow_anonymous false`.  Setting that to true resolved the issue.  It is unfortunate that the documentation mentions a password file, but not how this interacts with TLS.

Comment: Oh cool, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and although slightly different if may help others as it took me a long time and a lot of searching to find it.

Changing the certificate/key permissions fixed the issue for me.
E.g.

sudo chmod 744 raspberrypi.crt

sudo chmod 644 raspberrypi.key

As per this forum:-
https://github.com/owntracks/tools/issues/6